# Make access to VPN via another host in local network

Tags: networking, vpn, bridge, gateway

My network structure:

```
--------------          --------------
|   WINDOWS  |          |   LINUX    |
| VPN ACCESS |          |   NO VPN   |
--------------          --------------
      |                       |             101.101.0.1
  -----------------------------------------------------
   101.101.0.2          101.101.0.3             |
                                        --------------
                                        |   ROUTER   |
                                        --------------
                                                |           WAN
                                        ----------------------------
```

The problem I have is an access to VPN only from Windows host.
My Linux needs this access as well. Is it possible to use my Windows as a gateway in existing
network structure without adding aditional Ethernet interfaces to Windows host?

Comment: Are you saying the windows host is the VPN server, or is the only host with access to the VPN server?

Comment: This is only VPN client I have. This is not VPN server. I would like to share this access in my local network. The VPN server is on the WAN side.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking to make your VPN client into a router, allowing other clients to connect through it. What sort of client is it, windows native (L2TP/IPSeC | PPTP) or is it a software client?

Comment: This is IPSec Client from NCP.

Comment: You'll probably want to speak with NCP then, it seems like they offer some software to create gateways, I don't think that their client is likely to offer router type capabilities.. maybe I'm wrong tho.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As far as I know NCP doesn't offer this software for Linux. It seems I need to dig this topic yet.